# can't install ubuntu-sdk after installing ubuntu 14.04.2

Tags: 14.04, apt, dependencies, ubuntu-sdk

Now I can't install ubuntu-sdk and I can't resolve the problem. I used:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-sdk-team/ppa
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-sdk
```

but I have always problem with dependencies while installing ubuntu-sdk

```
ubuntu- sdk : Depends: ubuntu-sdk-libs-dev but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

What can I do? Thanks

Comment: execute 'sudo apt-get upgrade' before 'sudo apt-get dist-upgrade' and see whether the problem is resolved.

Comment: no there is the same problem :(

Comment: Can you manually "apt-get install ubuntu-sdk-libs-dev" and see what the output is, to determine why it won't install?

Comment: I just created an i386 14.04 chroot and issued the same commands. The ubuntu-sdk installed without any problem. I suspect that you have some older PPA enabled or packages from unofficial PPAs. would suggest to try to install manually the packages the apt reports as "not going to be installed" and also check the output of the apt-cache policy to see where the package would come from.

Comment: I can reproduce this issue on 14.04.2 clean install. Installing ubuntu-sdk-libs-dev wants to pull in libqt5webkit5-dev which pulls in the world. http://paste.ubuntu.com/10559268/

Comment: After so many months, this problem doesn't seems to be resolved, yet!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We are working on this issue, but one idea would be to do `sudo  apt-get install ubuntu-sdk-libs-dev libgl1-mesa-dev-lts-utopic libgles2-mesa-dev-lts-utopic`

I will check if it is a generic enough and permanent solution for this problem or not. But it worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

Nice solution for installing SDK:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk

wget http://dl.google.com/android/android-sdk_r24.2-linux.tgz

tar -xvf android-sdk_r24.2-linux.tgz

cd android-sdk-linux/tools
```

## chose what do you want to install:

```
./android update sdk
```

## Add sdk to your path:

```
nano ~/.bashrc
```

## Just insert this one line:

```
export PATH=${PATH}:$HOME/sdk/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools:$HOME/sdk/android-sdk-linux/tools:$HOME/sdk/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/22.0.1/
```

## After that just type one by one these lines:

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/<sdk installation location>/android-sdk-linux

export PATH=${PATH}:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools

source ~/.bashrc

sudo apt-get install libc6:i386 libstdc++6:i386

sudo apt-get install zlib1g:i386
```

Comment: `~/.zshrc` is for customization of the `zsh` shell. `bash` users (`echo $SHELL` if unsure) should make the same additions to `~/.bashrc`.

Comment: Yes,  you're right